# MPMoviePlayerViewController in a custom cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, mpmovieplayercontroller, subview

I have an app with a news feed screen, like the one in the facebook app. For this, I have made a custom cell, which has a `contentView` which is a `UIView`. This contentView gets initialized for displaying text, an image or video. This is done in the class for the custom cell. For the video, I'm trying to add MPMoviePlayerViewController as a subview to the cell's contentView:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:nil];
player.view.frame = self.contentView.frame;
player.view.tag = kVideoView;
[self.contentView addSubview:player.moviePlayer.view];
```

Then, when I load that cell in the tableviewcontroller, I want to give it contentURL, like this:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *controller = (MPMoviePlayerViewController *)[cell viewWithTag:kVideoView];
controller.moviePlayer.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:postInfo.uri];
return;
```

This crashes the app with an error:

```
-[MPMovieView moviePlayer]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are adding `player.moviePlayer.view` to content view.

So while retrieving you will get reference to `player.moviePlayer.view` only not `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

My suggestion is don't create multiple `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instance. You can add some `UIButton` or `UIImageView` on cell with snapshot of particular video. And while playing only you can create `MPMoviePlayerViewController` instance and play your video

Comment: I know that that's what's happening, I was just wondering how to get around it :)

Comment: The work around is to do what Bhumeshwer katre says. Don't load the movie into every cell. Just load a representative UIImage or play icon. Then when your user taps on that you can then create a new MPMoviePlayerController to play your movie. If you want to have a movie stream playing in each table row cell (I don't think this is a great idea) then you'll be better off taking a look at AVPlayer.

Comment: Great answer thank you! I was doing something similar. I was creating an instance of `MPMoviePlayerViewController` in each cell and it's definitely not working out as smoothly as I'd like.

Comment: @SuperKevin I've  created playImage on each cell now I'm wondering how to make the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to collectionView and when press play video ?